# How to enque scss on Wordpress

Tags: sass, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have this test Wordpress site http://test.fluxmusic.net/ and I have my css and js file working, but I can't find how to make scss files work.

Answer (score 1):

SCSS files must be compiled to css first before enqueuing them.  You will need to install a plugin like:

https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-scss/

Hope this helps